# POST Javascript; Error in JSON (FCM, Push to mobile)

Tags: javascript, rest

I am trying to send a push to my phone through rest.

i tried:

```
async function SendPush(event)
  {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.preventDefault();

    var tokenID = "xxx"

    let url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    let serverkey = 'yyy';
    
    let headers = new Headers();
    
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'key=' + serverkey);

    var dict = { 
      to : tokenID
      };
    
      let body = Object.entries(dict).map(([key, value]) => 
      encodeURIComponent(`params[${key}]`) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)).join('&');
  
  var res 
  
      await fetch(url, {
         method: 'POST',
          headers: { 
          Authorization: 'key=' + serverkey, 
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
         body: body
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => 
        {
          //console.log(data);
          res = data; // cannot return here. must await or something idk
        });


        console.log(res);
  }
```

This object works on c# and in postman. I followed this convention:

URL:
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Header:

"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "key=<Server_key>"

BODY:

```
{
    "to": "<Device FCM token>",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Check this Mobile (title)",
      "body": "Rich Notification testing (body)",
      "mutable_content": true,
      "sound": "Tri-tone"
      },

   "data": {
    "url": "<url of media image>",
    "dl": "<deeplink action on tap of notification>"
      }
}
```

But I am getting:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Can you tell me, where my error is?

Comment: Check what the `response` actually contained. (Log it to console, _before_ attempting to decode it as JSON, or checking using your browser dev tools.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
let body = JSON.stringify(dict)
```

instead of

```
let body = Object.entries(dict).map(([key, value]) => 
      encodeURIComponent(`params[${key}]`) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)).join('&');
```

The body in fetch must match "Content-Type" header